# How to include the Ansible config file in the ansible-playbook command?

Tags: ansible

I run my `ansible-playbook` with the following command in my localhost:

```
ansible-playbook -i "localhost," -c local GitClone.yaml
```

However, I also have a `GitClone.cfg` file which has:

```
[defaults]
transport = ssh

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

The `GitClone.cfg` file is in the same directory as the `GitClone.yaml` file.

**How do I include this file in the command?**

The command mentioned above is not picking up the .cfg file.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The proper name for the Ansible configuration file is `ansible.cfg`.

It is a fixed name and Ansible does not look for any other `.cfg` file unless you explicitly provided the path in `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` variable.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html). Ansible checks the files in the following order:

> - `ANSIBLE_CONFIG` (an environment variable)
> - `ansible.cfg` (in the current directory)
> - `.ansible.cfg` (in the home directory)
> - `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`

Comment: I think the correct link to the documentation is this:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html

Answer (score 3):

The above documentation link got expired

Here is the sample ansible.cfg file from ansible git repo
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/examples/ansible.cfg

Documentation link: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html

[image]

for checking which configuration values are active in a current directory. run the below commands will provide you the infromation
[image]